# How to start using OAuth in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, api, oauth

I'm completely new to Oauth 2.0 and I want to use it in my Silverlight (c#) in-browser application, in order to access this API method: https://www.elance.com/p/api2/methods/workroom/bid-id/messages.

What are the things that I need to know? Is there any library that I can use for this?

I would also appreciate some code examples!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fair amount of libraries for the protocol, including C#!

http://oauth.net/code/

Edit:

Plus, this link provides a thorough guide on the protocol, if RFCs are not your favorite nightstand literature:
http://hueniverse.com/oauth/